# How to add Asynchronous Loggers to Infinispan 13 using Helm

Tags: java, datagrid, log4j2, infinispan, helm3

I am trying to Add Asynchronous Logger to Infinispan Server using helm.
We follow this guide https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/manual/async.html to do this. But unfortunately we got the following error.

```bash
main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig for element AsyncLogger: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lmax/disruptor/EventHandler java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lmax.disruptor.EventHandler
```

I found a solution here https://mkyong.com/logging/log4j-2-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-lmax-disruptor-eventtranslatorvararg/

But I am using helm https://github.com/openshift-helm-charts/charts/tree/main/charts/redhat/redhat/data-grid/8.3.1 to deploy the Server.

The question is **"How I can add a dependency to our Server using Helm template. It is possible?"**

Thanks for your time

Alexis.

Answer (score 0):

The Infinispan server image allows dependencies to be resolved on startup via http/ftp/maven by specifying the `SERVER_LIBS` env variable with space separated artifacts. [More details here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-images#deploying-artifacts-to-the-server-lib-directory)

It's possible to modify the `templates/statefulset.yaml` to include the following env var `SERVER_LIBS=com.lmax:disruptor:3.4.2` in the "infinispan" container. This will result in the artifact being downloaded to each of the StatefulSet pods.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have changed `templates/statefulset.yaml` with the following value
`spec.template.spec.containers[0].env` 

`
- name: SERVER_LIBS
  value: "com.lmax:disruptor:3.4.2"
`
But when i deploy RHDG i got the following message **The command is not available in the current context.** and the pod doesnt starts

Comment: I have tried another alternative. I have created a confimap and i referenced it in the statefulset, but unfortunately i got the same mensaje and the pod never ups
`The command is not available in the current context.`
`Usage: cli [<options>]`

Comment: Apologies, but it seems like the `cli install` command is not enabled in the Red Hat Data Grid image. If you have a Red Hat subscription, this is something you can raise with support.

Alternatively, you can use the upstream image `quay.io/infinispan/server:13.0.10.Final` and the install command will work as expected.